# why sleeping is needed in a shell script file which is run within a java servlet

Tags: java, shell, servlets, avahi

I have a shell script `script.sh` which needs to be run both by a java servlet and by hand. Its content is:

```
service avahi-daemon restart
instance=MyInstance
avahi-publish -s -d local $instance _temp._tcp 443 "model=Model1"  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
# update: publish other services.
```

Update:
It is unable to remove the trailing &, because the `avahi-publish` would't return but keeps running once started and I need to publish other services.

And the servlet is:

```
public class DefaultServlet extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash script.sh");
            process.waitFor();
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, the service MyInstance won't be published if the servlet is accessed in a browser. But appending `sleep 0.1s` to the script file would solve it.

My question is that, is there any magic in the Runtime.exec() and why the `sleep` instruction is needed?

Comment: Since shell script is starting a background process (note the & at the end) for `avahi-publish`, the script will exit even before the `avahi-publish` is finished.

Comment: @learningloop thanks for the reply. But the process avahi-publish can be found in the result of `ps aux`.

Comment: maybe remove the redirection to /dev/null and see if any err msg is output

Comment: @TanJinfu Nobody said it wasn't. The point is that it can still be there after the script returns, and `Process.waitFor()`, and whatever the servlet does, and whatever the browser does when the servlet returns.

Answer (score 2):

```
avahi-publish -s -d local $instance _temp._tcp 443 "model=Model1"  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Because of the trailing `&`, this script will exit and `Process.waitFor()` will return before the `avahi-publish` command has finished.

Remove the trailing `&`.

You should also remove the redirection, and consume the output in the servlet, and test the exit status of the process. To assist in that I would use `exec` for the `avahi-publish` process.

Comment: The trailing & can't be removed as publishing other services is needed.

Comment: Do you really need a single script to publish them all?  Your servlet is running a script that starts a bunch of processes, but the servlet has no direct knowledge of those processes and can't monitor their status.  Consider using a separate script for each service — or forego the script entirely and have the servlet just run `avahi-publish` directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the Runtime.exec() doesn't work for me.  The ProcessBuilder  and a thread resolve my issue.

Comment: @TanJinfu I don't know why you're telling me. I haven't said anything about `Runtime.exec()`.

Comment: @EJP As I'm using the method in the above code and you mentioned `exec` in your answer so I'm thinking you are saying it. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found that ProcessBuilder helps me. Here are my psudo code:

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    new HandlerThread("avahi-publish","-s","-d", "local","MyInstance", "_https._tcp",
     "443","model=abc")
    .start();
}

private static class HandlerThread extends Thread {
    Process process;

    HandlerThread(String... args) {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(args);
        process = processBuilder.start();
    }

    public void run() {
         StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            process.waitFor();
            readStream(process.getInputStream(),stringBuilder);
            readStream(process.getErrorStream(),stringBuilder);
        }catch( IOException|InterruptedException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuilder);
    }
    private static String readStream(InputStream inputStream, StringBuilder sb) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append('\n');
            }
        } finally {
            if(br!=null) br.close();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: So you did manage to remove the trailing `&`, which is surely what fixed your problem. You should read the streams before calling `Process.waitFor()`, not after. Your present implementation can deadlock if the process produces a lot of output.

Comment: Yes, I did remove the trailing `&`, but only removing it and calling `waitFor` would block the Servlet thread, because `avahi-publish' keeps running without complete once started.

Comment: I just tested reading the streams before calling `Process.waitFor()`, the readStream blocks and never runs to the waitFor() method.